# Calculate percentage shows only 100 perc PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count, percentage

I am truing to calculate the ration and I don't understand why it shows only 0 or 100. The formula is working properly when I am not putting it together:

```
case 
    when (count(status_id) filter (where status_id = 2)) = 0 then 0 
    else ((count(status_id) filter (where status_id = 2))/count(status_id))*100 end as conversion_rate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called integer division: since both the numerator and the denominator are integer values, Postgres produces an integer result.

To avoid it, you can do:

```
case when (count(status_id) filter (where status_id = 2)) = 0 
    then 0 else 
    100.0 * count(status_id) filter (where status_id = 2) / count(status_id) 
end as conversion_rate
```